# Variadic function causing SIGILL signal with enums

Tags: c++, enums, variadic-functions

Is it possible to pass an enum as a parameter to a variadic function? I'm trying to do the following:

```
GLenum ShaderManager::initialize()
{
    GLuint program = loadShader("Flat", 2, ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX, "coord3d", ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE0, "texcoord");

    //...
}


GLuint ShaderManager::loadShader(std::string shaderName, ... )
{
    GLuint program;

    //...

    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, shaderName);

    int count = va_arg(arglist, int);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        AttributeLocation location = va_arg(arglist, AttributeLocation);
        char * name = va_arg(arglist, char *);
        glBindAttribLocation(program, location, name);
    }
    va_end(arglist);

    //...
}
```

Where both `ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX` and `ATTRIBUTE_TExTURE` are declared as

```
enum AttributeLocation {
        ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX = 0,
        ATTRIBUTE_COLOR,
        ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE0
    };
```

But the program just terminates. I've found out, debugging the program, that the error occurs on the first line after the for loop. So I'm wondering if it is possible to do it or it's something illegal.

Comment: I don't think the error is in this code, you'll have to post more.

Comment: @SethCarnegie actually I think it is, because if I change only `AttributeLocation location = va_arg(arglist, AttributeLocation);` to `int location = va_arg(arglist, int);` it works as expected. Anyway, I'll post more related code.

Comment: ah thanks. I have figured out what was wrong, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because passing integral types that are less than `sizeof(int)` bytes big to a varargs function will convert them up to `sizeof(int)` bytes when passed on the stack. If `AttributeLocation` smaller than `sizeof(int)` bytes, then `sizeof(int)` bytes are pushed on the stack, but you retrieve only `sizeof(AttributeLocation)` bytes from the stack with the `va_arg` call. Then when you try to read the `char*`, you get the rest of the bytes of the `AttributeLocation` and some of the bytes of the `const char*` that you passed.

Comment: So it seems that the best solution is to simply pass an enum and retrieve an integer using va_arg, if I've undertood correctly.

Comment: @Narrakan yes, that is what would be best.

Comment: What you say is correct (in fact what I've seen is even if you have only 1 variable argument and use va_arg(list, char) to retrieve it, it causes SIGILL to be raised). My question is do you have any reference material for this?